# What possible reasons are behind the GBP -> EUR rate being the same for a few days?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, volatility

The GBP -> EUR exchange rate has been stuck at a value of 1.11 since Saturday 7 of September, up from 1.10 since the day before. This seems to me highly irregular, as if all trading activity has stopped. But even without major activity there should still be some fluctuation in the price, however minor.

Is this kind of activity normal in Forex? What reasons are / could be behind it?

[image: GBP and EUR exchange rate screenshot from Google]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forex markets are [closed on weekends](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/forex/f/forex-market-trading-hours.asp), so the prices are stale.